# vlc fonts too small

Tags: fonts, vlc

My system:
AMD A8-7650K Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
memory: 15338MB
System  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS     3840x2160 pixels
AMD KAVERI (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-33-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)

I am using a 4k tv for my monitor
my resolution is 3840x2160
I am using vlc 4.0.0

I have tried to use gnome tweaks but none of those setting will deal with the vlc fonts. I have also messed with ubuntu settings but nothing there will change the fonts either.  I should also mention that this is not isolated to just vlc as I have the same problem with Stacer.

Thank you............

The fonts in vlc are very small

Answer (score 3):

Vlc and stacer use QT as a graphical user interface. That's why you don't see other applications with the smaller fonts/icon issues.

To fix this solution install qt5ct and execute the following in the command line;

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2

vlc
```

Comment: Or use the QT5 configuration tool - qt5ct

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the perfect solution but open the terminal and type:

```
xrandr --dpi 288
vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply.  I don't have the guts to try xrandr because I only have a problem with specific applications and this will deal with all the fonts in my system (I think).  Setting up this system to use a 4k tv as a monitor was a bit pesky from the getgo and don't really want to mess with it as its working. I think the font thing comes from what was used to create these programs from the beginning.  I have noted that there have been suggestions for that one too but I am hoping somebody a lot smarter than I can give me a specific solution.

I also know that this only happens when I am using the 4k monitor and not when I am using, say, 1920x1080 on a normal monitor so I know this has something to do with the running with a 4k monitor (3840x2160) which is simply not recognized by the program itself.  I suspect the font being used by vlc has a size that is kinda set in stone.  The problem is that I can't get to the font to figure out what it is and where it comes from.

Here is the same problem by somebody else who has exactly the same problem and tried on the vlc forum:

I just upgraded to Xubuntu 18.04 from 16.04, and I am running VLC 3.0.3. On my old installation, VLC obeyed the setting for the system fonts (which is a gtk setting because it is XFCE), which I have set very large so I can see them on my 50 inch screen from far away. Now, however, the fonts are extremely small.

I thought (I think) that VLC pulled the font settings from qt5, and so I installed qt5ct and changed the font preferences there. But there was no change.

I also tried starting vlc with the `-style gtk` as I thought most qt options allowed, but it seems this is not an option.

Can someone please tell me where VLC gets its font settings and maybe point me in the right direction to change them? I will try any workaround. I just need to be able to see the menu. :)

Thanks in advance.
Top

Kallaste
    New Cone
    New Cone
    Posts: 3
    Joined: 17 Oct 2015 06:35

Re: Menu font sizes and qt5ct

```
Quote
```

Postby Kallaste » 19 Aug 2018 05:08
Well, 8 days later and nothing. I had forgotten no one bothers to respond at this forum. I'm really not sure why you keep it up.

I will just use another player. I would have been willing to do the research and write a fix for this myself, if anyone on the project had simply had the courtesy to say, sorry, we don't know. But if you don't care, neither do I.
Top